# Django list ordering by date

Tags: python, django

I want to display in the same page all the results of this 2 queries and ordering them by date. The goal is to mix both results to just display a unique list ordering by date.

```
articles = Articles.objects.all()

statut = Statut.objects.all()
```

I have this idea but I don't know :

```
articles = list(Articles.objects.all())

statut = list(Statut.objects.all())

all = articles + statut
```

So I have a unique list and it's working. It displays every results.

Now I wonder how to order by date for the template rendering?

May be there is a simpler way to do it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to `chain` 2 querysets together and the apply `sorted` to them:

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import attrgetter

articles = list(Articles.objects.all())

statut = list(Statut.objects.all())

result_list = sorted(
    chain(articles, statut),
    key=attrgetter('date_created')) # date_created name may differ
```

Comment: Many thanks @pythad
I just add reverse=True and it's OK !

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..., my suggestion is sorting them on front-end with some js framework, e.g., jquery.